# Expanding on APEX Class Method

Tags: apex, trigger, class, method

I have a class method that is assigning a Team to a contact record based on the value from another field. I want to expand this logic so that I don't have to write out multiple methods for each team and use only one method. This logic I have works, but as stated, would need to write multiple methods for each team. Can anyone help?

```
trigger FUSContactTrigger on Contact (after insert, after update) {

    if(checkRecursive.runOnce())
    {

    //Freshman Team Assignment    
    List<Contact> FreshmanTeam = New List<Contact>();
    List<String> FreshmanTypes = new List<String> { 'U - Senior' , 'U - Senior Transfer', 'U - Transfer', 'U - UG Readmit', 'U - UG Readmit Transfer', 'U - Post-Secondary' };

    for(Contact c: Trigger.New) {
        if(FreshmanTypes.contains(c.TargetX_SRMb__Student_Type__c) && c.Team_Assignment__c != 'Freshman Team') {
            FreshmanTeam.add(c);
        } 
    }

    if(FreshmanTeam.size() > 0) {
    FUSContactController ctrl = New FUSContactController();
    ctrl.FreshmanTeamAssignment(FreshmanTeam);
    }

    }//End Check Recursion

}
```

```
public class FUSContactController {

    public void FreshmanTeamAssignment(List<Contact> Contacts) {
        List<Contact> FreshmanTeamAssignment = new List<Contact>();

        for(Contact c : Contacts) {
            FreshmanTeamAssignment.add(new Contact(id=c.id, Team_Assignment__c = 'Freshman Team'));
        }

        if(FreshmanTeamAssignment.size() > 0) {
            update FreshmanTeamAssignment;
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: `runOnce()` is perhaps the worst possible way to cope with trigger recursion and actively breaks your code in a variety of real-world situations.

Comment: Thanks @DavidReed. I am in the process of trying to clean up my org and it was only meant to be temporary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a parameter:

```
public class FUSContactController {
    public static void FreshmanTeamAssignment(List<Contact> Contacts, String teamName) {
        for(Contact c : Contacts) {
            c.Team_Assignment__c = teamName;
        }
        update FreshmanTeamAssignment;
    }   
}
```

Note all the optimizations; you don't need to create new records in memory, you don't need a no-op DML guard, and you can use static methods to avoid constructing objects, reducing code use. That's obsolete programming design, as DML operations automatically ignore empty lists.